# Attempting to print mysql results array into javascript, array undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

My Goal is to print out information from a php array into a javascript alert box, my array in php is $arrayOfPhotos, I set its values with this code below, I believe this would be multi-dimensional array because each row will have many attributes with it.

```
$query = "SELECT displayname, time, title, description, comments, ratings, email, filename FROM photo ORDER BY time DESC";
if(!$result = $_db->query($query))
    {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $_db->error . ']');
    }        

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
                   $arrayOfPhotos[] = $row;
        }
```

After this while loop is ran i have this code below

```
 $js_array = array();
    $js_array = json_encode($arrayOfPhotos);

   echo" <script> var arrayOfPhotos = '.$js_array.'; </script>" ;
      echo '<script>alert(arrayOfPhotos[0].filename);</script>';
```

So when the alert box pops up, it just prints undefined. I would like to be able to print to javascript values in the array at index like i attempted too. I have a feeling it may be a basic syntax error but I'm having trouble figuring this out, Thanks alot for helping me!

Comment: View the page source that is generated.

Comment: Please show/echo var_dump $js_array....

Comment: Your issue is probably with `'.$js_array.'` in `echo" <script> var arrayOfPhotos = '.$js_array.'; </script>" ;`. remove the `'.`/`.'`.

Comment: @Sean thank you so much, flawless fix. after changing '.$js_array.' to just $js_array, that 100% fixed it. All that frustration over a little syntax. thank you!!!

Comment: no problem. `json_encode()` already provides you with valid syntax, and so it is very common issue when people invalidate the result.